# Spark - calculate the sum of features for each sample

Tags: python, apache-spark

If I have a RDD which looks like below then I know how to calculate the sum of my features per sample data:

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark import SparkContext

x = np.arange(10) # first sample with 10 features [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
y = np.arange(10) # second sample with 10 features [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
z = (x,y)
sc = SparkContext()
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(z)
rdd1.sum()
```

The output will be an array like this: ([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]), which is what I want.

My Question is:
If I construct a RDD by parsing a csv file as below, in which each element of the RDD is a tuple or list. How can I calculate the sum of each tuple/list elements (each feature) like above? If I use the sum I get this error:

```
Rdd :  [(0.00217010083485, 0.00171658370653), (7.24521659993e-05, 4.18413109325e-06), ....]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

**[EDIT]** To be more specific:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,3),(2,4)])
```

I want my output to be [3,7].  Each tuple is a data instance that I have, and each element of tuple is my feature.  I want to calculate the sum of each feature per all data samples.

Comment: Is `rdd.map(sum)` what you want?

Comment: what is your expected output for the `rdd`? can you share a smalle reproducible example just as your first codechunk?

Comment: @Psidom: No rdd.map(sum) gives me the sum for each tuple.  What I need is get the sum of first, second elements of all tuples.  Lets assume we have a rdd of rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,3),(2,4)]).  The output of the rdd.map(sum).collect() will be [4,6].  What I want is: [3,7].

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you will need the `reduce` method, zip the two consecutive tuples and add them element by element:

```
rdd.reduce(lambda x, y: [t1+t2 for t1, t2 in zip(x, y)])
# [3, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have a huge csv file, in each row I have a sample data with 40 features.  So each of the tuples belong to one data sample and I want to calculate the mean, std  for each feature.  That is why I am asking for this.  Before your answer I was creating a spark dataframe and then calculate all these.

Comment: If you have a csv file, data frame will indeed be a better/easier way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
z = zip(x, y)
#z is [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2) ......]
map(np.sum, z)
```

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I just add the solution using PySpark dataframe for larger rdd that you have

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 3),(2, 4)])
df = rdd.toDF() # tranform rdd to dataframe
col_sum = df.groupby().sum().rdd.map(lambda x: x.asDict()).collect()[0]
[v for k, v in col_sum.asDict().items()] # sum of columns: [3, 7]
```

Comment: your solution is not what I am looking for.  I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: I updated solution using Pyspark dataframe, hope this is complimentary of above solution.

Comment: This solution would not necessarily keep the sum of representative data in its location ([7,3]).  Try to add another tuple, you will see my point.  thanks

Comment: I see. This is actually from `.values()`. I use Python 3 so it returns values in order. You can use `iteritems()` or `items()` instead. I'll change my solution accordingly later on.